# Storing image in SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, sharedpreferences

```
mHomePage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });
    mHomePage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // When an Image is picked
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri resultUri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(resultUri)
                .start(getActivity());
    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        Uri uri = result.getUri();

        Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=shre.edit();
        edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
        edit.commit();

    }
```

Trying to store image in sharedpreference by encoding but I'm new to this and not able to figure it out. I saw some questions related to this problem but those aren't clear. Can someone help me out on how to store path/image in `SharedPreferences`?

Code isn't even compiling as I have put a uri in inout stream in `.decodeStream()`.

Answer (score 1):

The Uri points to the path where the image is stored, so first you would have to read it with `InputStream`.

This code will fix the compilation error. As a side-node, use `edit.apply()` instead of `edit.commit()`.

```
if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
    try
    {
        InputStream ims = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

        SharedPreferences shre = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit=shre.edit();
        edit.putString("image_data",encodedImage);
        //edit.commit();
        edit.apply();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I don't really see a point in storing an image in SharedPreferences? It's not really meant for that. Why don't you use save the file in `context.getFilesDir()` and read it from there when you need it? It's better than encoding/decoding it.